# Updating a Tkinter Gui in Python while running the program

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

So the program I am writing basically retrieves info from a CSV file and puts it into a SQLite Database. I am trying to make a GUI for it to show selected info.
In the code below the "from Populate_DB import *" gives me a few functions that i put onto the buttons (building the Database basically).

What i am trying to do is have the GUI that has the functionality to build the database (the two importbuttons) and when I press the 'baseButton' builds a list with data from the DB (via the List_base function) and puts this in the combo box.

This however doesnt work since I cant get the progrom to update after building the database and then building the base list (into the variable 'dropdownVals'). Is there a way to make the program update? Later on I want to expand on this by taking input from the combobox (a base name you can select) to use as input for a new list (a list of items that is sold at this base --- it basically is data from the game Freelancer). Can i somehow use a .update() or something in the likes? I did not get this to work.

```
from Tkinter import *
import csv, sqlite3, sys
from Populate_DB import *
from ttk import Combobox

dropdownVals = []

def List_bases():
    sql = cur.execute('SELECT DISTINCT Base FROM Commodities')
    data = cur.fetchall()
    for i in data:
        neat = ' '.join(map(str, (i)))
        dropdownVals.append(neat)

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.drop = Combobox(frame, values=dropdownVals)
        self.drop.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)

        self.quitButton = Button(frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", cnf={},
            command=quit)
        self.quitButton.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)

        self.importButton = Button(frame, text="Import data",
            command=self.de)
        self.importButton.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)

        self.importCleanButton = Button(frame, text="Import clean",
            command=self.de_c)
        self.importCleanButton.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w', padx=5,
            pady=5)

        self.baseButton = Button(frame, text="Bases", command=self.base)
        self.baseButton.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)

    def de(self):
        data_entry()

    def de_c(self):
        data_entry_clean()

    def base(self):
        List_bases()
        print "bases!"

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: To update a widget in tkinter you may want to have a look at "events and bindings", at the "after" function, which belongs to every widget, and, eventually if you're not able to do it with the previous tools (but you should!), you could have a look at threads. It's difficult for us to help you with a problem which involves other libraries and files which we can't access easily. Ideally we would like to try your program so that we observe the concrete problem to give concrete answers, otherwise you will receive answer as mine above (in this same comment).

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look into that. I was thinking about how to give the code thats not in here but tonight I'll try and edit it a bit to give some of the other code in some way or other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, next time you give us an example that we can run without having to modify the code. For example, the whole DB thing is not needed here. The problem is not with the DB but with the updating of the combobox.

The solution is very easy. The combobox does not reference your dropdownVals but rather copies it. So changhing the dropdownVals does not affect Tkinter. You have to supply the dropdownVals to the dropdownbox every time you update them:

```
from Tkinter import *
import csv, sqlite3, sys
#from Populate_DB import *
from ttk import Combobox

def List_bases():
    """sql = cur.execute('SELECT DISTINCT Base FROM Commodities')
    data = cur.fetchall()
    for i in data:
        neat = ' '.join(map(str, (i)))
        dropdownVals.append(neat)
    """
    dropdownVals = []
    for i in ["test1", "test2"]:
        dropdownVals.append(i)
    return dropdownVals

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        dropdownVals = []

        self.drop = Combobox(frame, values=dropdownVals)
        self.drop.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)

        self.quitButton = Button(frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", cnf={},
            command=quit)
        self.quitButton.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)

        self.importButton = Button(frame, text="Import data",
            command=self.de)
        self.importButton.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)

        self.importCleanButton = Button(frame, text="Import clean",
            command=self.de_c)
        self.importCleanButton.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w', padx=5,
            pady=5)

        self.baseButton = Button(frame, text="Bases", command=self.base)
        self.baseButton.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)

    def de(self):
        data_entry()

    def de_c(self):
        data_entry_clean()

    def base(self):
        dropdownVals = List_bases()
        self.drop.config(values=dropdownVals)
        print "bases!"

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! This works! I am wondering however what exactly does the line self.drop.config(values=dropdownVals) do? dropdownVals = List_bases() puts the list from the List_bases() method into the variable dropdownVals which gets passed into the next line values. But the self.drop.config part I'm not sure about.

Comment: Config takes in the same arguments as when the combobox is created. So that you can change the widgets properties after the creation. The ttk combobox inhertis this from the Tkinter.Widget. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-configuration.htm

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem using the threading library in python3:

```
import threading
from tkinter import *

class MyApp():
   #my app code
   def __init__(self, mywin):
      self.mywin = mywin

mywin = Tk()
myapp = MyApp(mywin)

def mainloop():
   while True:
      #my loop function

threading.Thread(target=mainloop).start()
mywin.mainloop()
```

In short, the threading library will make your loop run in the background while the tkinter loop keeps running normally.